# Eclipse loads separate activities instead of application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, load, device

I'm using Eclipse and android SDK (with ADT Plugin), I don't know if it's some kind of configuration issue or it's some code problem. Whenever I load an app that I made from scratch (this means not using another existing code or one sample from the library) to my device or run it on the emulator, the entire app will load as "separate" apps, which are the activities. For example, if the app is named "Hello world" and it has two activities, "MainActivity" and "SecondaryActivity", both of them will show up on the device with their names as app names and sharing the app icon on the menu. Now, if I go to settings, "Hello World" appears as an application, now behaving again like it should. This doesn't affect the operation of the app, however, it's annoying to have more than 1 icon launching the same app. The problem is that, when i first used eclipse, this was not happening.

Just in case it helps, I've already re-installed the entire android SDK and the ADT plugin, as well, I tried using 3 different Eclipse versions (classic, EE, and Java developers), none of them seem to work, even though, in the Graphical Layout for any activity, the name of the app is showed in the bar with the app's icon, but running on the emulator or a real device it shows the activity's name there instead. I've looked everywhere and I haven't solved the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: How are activities listed in your AndoidManifest.xml?

Comment: @kostja the problem appears even if there is only one activity (the name of the activity appears beneath the icon on the menu, not on "application management"). They are listed as: <application(icon,label and theme inside) <activity(name and label inside) <intent-filter> <action(name) /> <category(name) /> <intent-filter/> <activity /> <application />.

Comment: Hmm, if you have a single activity in the manifest but multiple activities get deployed, then Im clueless. Sry

Comment: @kostja The number of activities that the app has, it's the number of icons the device shows (All icons with corresponding activities' names). If I have one single activity contained in the app, the device or the emulator will show the activity's name instead of the app's name but only on the menu. If you have the Android SDK and the ADT Plugin with Eclipse, create an Android Application Project and leave everything in the deffault settings, just by doing that and loading the app with a "Blank activity" will result in the device showing the activity's name. Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your manifest to see if more than one activity has this:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: Oh! Yes, all of the activities have category set as Launcher, that's why they appear on the menu? what should it say instead for an activity that's not meant to be the launcher? or does it deppend on the purpose of the activity? Solved! thanks a lot!

Comment: The "intent-filter" section defines ways your Activity can be launched, whether by a service that's running in the background or the launcher or even another Application. I'd suggest you read more about this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 4):

The answer I found for the above problem is, replace **category.LAUNCHER** to **category.EMBED** in all the activities apart from the MainActivity in your manifest file.